# Cannot load PostgresQL module in phpinfo()

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

Setting up Apache / Php / Postgres on Windows.

Apache is installed and service pages, Postgres is running fine, Phpinfo() works.

But I cannot seem to get the postgres module to show up in phpinfo() no matter what I try.

Path has been updated on windows to include

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin;C:\php;
```

These lines are uncommitted in php.ini and the correct ini is loading, and apache has been restarted...

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

PHP Version 5.4.45
Apache is 2.4.18
PostgresQL is 9.5

Comment: Try to specify the full path to the .dlls in the php.ini

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!  extension=c:\php\ext\php_pgsql.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the full path to the .dlls in the php.ini